# Invalid use of non static data member

Tags: c++, class, oop

```
class matrix
{
   public:
     int m;
     int n;
     int mat[m][n];
};
```

I get this error:

> [Error]: Invalid use of non static data member 'matrix::n'
>   On declaring static:

```
class matrix
{
   public:
     static int m;
     static int n;
     int mat[m][n];    //Error
};
```

I get this error:

> [Error]: Array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
>   Please tell me what these errors mean and how to fix this problem.

Comment: Please don't downvote questions simply because you think the answer is obvious. IMHO this question is well-posed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sizes of arrays in C++ must be compile-time evaluable.

The compiler doesn't know what to do with `int mat[m][n];` since the values of `m` and `n` are not known at compile time.

If you want a good reliable matrix class then consider using the BLAS library in Boost. A `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` *can* work but it is a *jagged-edged* matrix with a rather poor memory model.

Comment: Very valuable that you spell out the caveats with vector of vector.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you declare `mat` the member variables `m` and `n` doesn't actually exist. They don't exist until you create a an instance of the `matrix` class. However that won't do much good as arrays in C++ must have a fixed size at the time of compilation.

If you want to set the size of `mat` at run-time, then the simple solution here is to use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) objects.

Like e.g.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat;
```